# UseEffect return value

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that basically executes a backend function to return an integer.

I'm basically executing this:

```
  export async function CheckSupply() {
    const near = await connect(getConfig);
    const account = await near.account("myaddress");
    const supply = await account.viewFunction(
        "myaddress", 
        "nft_total_supply", 
        {}
    )
  }
```

using

```
import { CheckSupply } from "./utils";

    useEffect(() => {
     CheckSupply();
    },[]);
```

This seems to run fine, but I can't seem to get the value that is being returned from the function and not sure why?

Any help would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: well, the function doesn't return anything, and you aren't trying to obtain the return value...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kevin. Would you be able to explain what I should be doing. I’m a total beginner with react. What function doesn’t return a value? The useEffect?

Comment: Nothing you have returns anything, so asking why you can't get the return value doesn't make sense. Nothing is trying to receive a return value, and nothing is trying to return one.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: Ok. But when I check the value of checkSupply using === 33 it works. I know the value if I run the cmd in cli.

Comment: Your function must be different from what you've provided then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CheckSupply doesn't currently have a return statement. I'm assuming the value you care about is `supply`, so you would do:

```
  export async function CheckSupply() {
    const near = await connect(getConfig);
    const account = await near.account("myaddress");
    const supply = await account.viewFunction(
        "myaddress", 
        "nft_total_supply", 
        {}
    )
    return supply; // <----- added
  }
```

You also don't have any code that uses the return value, so you'll need to add that. Note that since CheckSupply is an async function, it will be returning a promise, so you'll need to `await` that promise to interact with the eventual `supply` value:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const load = async () => {
    const supply = await CheckSupply();
    // Do something with `supply`. Maybe set state?
  };
  load();
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and explanation Nicholas. That makes sense.

Comment: the `supply` should just return a number. I want to present that number in my App.  Is the userEffect the correct thing to do? What's the simplest way to enable me to just show the value?

Comment: Create a state variable and use that variable in the render output from App. `useEffect` is the correct spot to kick off the load, and when the data has been fetched you'll set state to cause the component to rerender.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, is this right:
```
    const [Total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const load = async () => {
          const supply = await CheckSupply();
          setTotal(supply)
        };
        load();
      }, [])
```

Comment: Yes, that looks like what i would expect.